# Superheterodyne receiver with voltage controlled oscillator

Tags: oscillator, radio, frequency-modulation, radar

I'm new in electronics and I want to create a FM receiver that performs a product of the received  RF signal and a local signal (the local signal is also frequency modulated with a Voltage Controlled Oscillator). I was thinking that a voltage controlled tunning receiver circuit could work. If true, where can I find a circuit diagram or in what kind of device could I find something that does what I want?

More details as requested: I'm trying to do a [Frequency modulated continuous wave radar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-wave_radar#Modulated_continuous-wave). No after demodulation is needed, the product signal will be sampled to a computer. The difference with any normal FM receiver is that I want my local oscillator to be a VCO. The band would be around 800Mhz.

Comment: Superheterodyne = performs a product of the received RF signal and a local signal. What band? What modulation index? What received minimum power? What power supply? Plenty of stuff to state before anyone might offer a circuit.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You seem to be describing the process used in most FM receivers where the incoming signal is mixed (multiplied) with a local oscillator to get a signal at the IF frequency for eventual demodulation and audio amplification.  Depending on the receiver, the local oscillator control can be a tuning capacitor, a voltage, or a digital synthesizer.

Comment: I'm trying to do a Frequency modulated continuous wave radar. No after demodulation is needed, the product signal will be sampled to a computer. The difference with any normal FM receiver is that I want my local oscillator to be a VCO. The band would be around 800Mhz.

Comment: @Mehdi asselman: I've copied your last comment into the question. In general, it's a good idea to make the question text self-contained.

Comment: This sounds a bit ambitions as a project for someone new to electronics. You can find [plenty of papers proposing one circuit or another for FMCW radar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=fmcw+circuit). I don't know much about the topic myself, but hopefully someone will suggest something easy to build, although easy is probably going to be relative to a certain skillset...

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you want a product and not just a mixer for FMCW. See https://github.com/lukeweston/SimpleFMCWRadar for example, where HMC219 is used for what I think you want to use your product.

Comment: And http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-ll-003-build-a-small-radar-system-capable-of-sensing-range-doppler-and-synthetic-aperture-radar-imaging-january-iap-2011/projects/ (also uses a mixer).

Comment: I'm confused, a product detector isn't the same as a mixer (frequency mixer) in this case? My aim is to obtain the difference of frequencies of input and oscillator signals. The difference between MIT radar and mines is that the transmitter and receiver parts are separated. It is not going to be a reflection radar, so I thought it would be much simpler As the transmitter is a classic FM transmitter and the receiver a superhetorodyne receiver with a VCO as local oscillator.

Comment: Anyways, the superheterodyne does have a mixer right?

Comment: Yes, the [same type of (frequency) mixer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_mixer) is used in both kinds of circuits (FMCW and superhet); the MIT project uses a [ZX05-43MH-S+](http://194.75.38.69/pdfs/ZX05-43MH+.pdf), which is boxy device with an internal schematic that seems identical to the one showed on Wikipedia for a double-balanced passive diode mixer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm planning to use a NE612 mixer, is it possible to couple it to a vco? how? what kind of things should I care about?